# Globbing multiple sequences in Python

Tags: python, python-3.6, glob

I'm using glob in Python 3.6 and trying to sequence match instead of using for loops:

```
glob("./*/*/*.(txt|json)")
glob("./*/(subdir1|subdir2)/*")
```

I was told this should work but it doesn't. Is this an issue with my syntax or is this functionality not supported?

Comment: What are you trying to match, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: Just multiple filetypes at the same time. I could loop through a list like ['txt', 'json'] and glob a filepath with it but I wanted to see if this syntax worked

Comment: In short: not possible with glob. You'll need to do multiple calls. In one folder os.listdir + regexp matching on the result can work (though you want to span multiple folders according to your question so probably won't be good for you).

Comment: Yes it does help. Awesome thanks for the answer!